# How to fix "Error reading from socket - bad file descriptor" while in thread on Linux using C?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, descriptor

I am setting up a server-client application(chat) and i have encountered a problem with sockets/threads. Both server and client run on Linux.

I want the server to be able to serve multiple users, and to do it I want to use threads from *pthread.h*, so every logged user has his own thread.

This is the **server**:
**main.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "manazerUctov.h"

int pocetVlakienZOP = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t* vlaknaZiadosti = 
    (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*POCET_UZIVATELOV);

    int sockfd, newsockfd;
    socklen_t cli_len;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int n;

    // Program
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage %s port\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    bzero((char*) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        perror("Error creating socket\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket OK\n");

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) < 0) {
        perror("Error binding socket address\n");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("Bind OK\n");

    listen(sockfd, 5);
    while (1) {

        cli_len = sizeof (cli_addr);

        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &cli_len);
        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            perror("ERROR on accept\n");
            return 3;
        }
        printf("Accept OK\n");
        client_data* cdata = (client_data*) malloc(sizeof (client_data));
        cdata->socket = newsockfd;

        pthread_t vlakno;
        vlaknaZiadosti[pocetVlakienZOP++] = vlakno;
        pthread_create(&vlakno, NULL, &serveClient, &cdata);
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**manazerUctov.h**:

```
#ifndef MANAZERUCTOV_H
#define MANAZERUCTOV_H

#ifndef POCET_UZIVATELOV
#define POCET_UZIVATELOV 256
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    char *buffer;
    char* msg;                         
    int socket;
} client_data;

void* serveClient(void* pdata);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* MANAZERUCTOV_H */
```

**manazerUctov.c** Here, the read function is giving error:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "manazerUctov.h"

void* serveClient(void *pdata) {
    char buffer[256];
    client_data* client = (client_data*)pdata;
    bzero(buffer, 256);

    int n = read(client->socket, buffer, 255);
    if (n < 0) {
        perror("Error reading from socket\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("Read from socket\n");
    close(client->socket);
}
```

When the client sends socket, the server accepts it and creates a thread, but I get **Error reading from socket: bad file descriptor**.
And the program is stuck, it won't even exit. And as far as I am concerned the sockets aren't closed yet.
Before I implemented threads, reading from sockets worked correctly.

EDIT: Original code is 500 lines long, so I trimmed it and the former error was no more, although another error was *&cdata* in *pthread_create* . Removing & solved the problem in both trimmed and original code and server is working.

Comment: *And the program is stuck, it won't even exit* - because you have a `while(1)` loop without any terminating condition? Except of the socket opening error. Closing the sockets and other cleanup should be done in the corresponding threads.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thank you for reply, i know about the terminating condition, that is for later :) ... I will move the closing function.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't build the code with `cdata->socket = sockfd;`?

Comment: To start with, you want the `listen` _above_ the loop, not _inside_ it (i.e. `listen` should be called just once).

Comment: @CristiFati yes I am, i tried `cdata->socket = sockfd;` and that gave the same error.

Comment: There is some problem with the code you posted (in the sense that **it's not the one you're running** (`close(socketfd);`)). Please post your actual code as described in [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, for such a small program, removing `main` and the `#include` doesn't help us. For an MCVE, we should be able to download, cleanly compile, link, and run your program if we so choose. So, please post your _entire_ program in a _single_ code block.

Comment: And, if we're to help debugging your server it would help to have your _client_ code as well [in a separate code block], so we have a way to test the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `pthread_create` function call is *incorrect*.

This passes a pointer to the `client_data` *pointer* and *not* what the pointer points to:

```
pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &my_function, &cdata);
```

What you want is:

```
pthread_create(&my_thread, NULL, &my_function, cdata);
```

So, instead of getting `cdata->socket`, you'll get the lower 32 bits of the pointer value as your file descriptor.

---

Some additional notes:

Because you have a loop scoped `pthread_t my_thread;`, this disappears on each iteration of the loop, so the main thread won't be able to do a `pthread_join` on it.

So, when your thread function exits, it will be in an unjoined (i.e. zombie) state.

Also, on each iteration, each `pthread_create` call may point to `my_thread` at the *same* address. I'm not sure what effect this will have on other thread primitives, but I'd be wary.

You may want to add the `pthread_t mythread;` to your allocated struct. That way, it is guaranteed to have a unique address. And, the main thread can keep track of the structs it has allocated.

Another way to deal with this is to have your thread function do a `pthread_detach` at the top [or add the appropriate attributes to the `pthread_create` call]

This may be easier cleaner.

Also, be sure that your thread function closes its socket and does a `free` on the struct pointer just before exiting.

Comment: You're welcome. I just added some notes on some other issues I see.